# Creating a "cut out" layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now, I have it so that my layout consists of a `Fragment` that takes up the entire screen and displays an image.  I want to make it so that an additional `View` exists on top of it, also taking up the entire screen.  On that top layer, I want to be able to color it all black initially, and then create certain spots that are transparent (alpha?) and reveal the image displayed on the fragment behind it.  So basically the screen will be all black except for a few spots where the image behind is showing through, which I would determine programmatically.  I've looked into a bunch of the graphics and views that Android provides, but have no clue where to start.  Is this suited for a SurfaceView if I just want it to be all black with some spots of alpha?

Once I select the correct view to use, I'm assuming that I just override the `onDraw()` method and then do something like `canvas.setBody(black)` and then add shapes of alpha to it?  Will the shapes correctly affect the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your masking `View`, you can make a custom view that can keep track of which areas to unmask (as `Rect`s or something similar) and then draw them in `onDraw(Canvas)` like this:

```
public class MaskView extends View {

    private Set<Rect> mRects = new HashSet<Rect>();
    private Paint mUnmaskPaint = new Paint();
    {
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    /**
     * Add an unmasking rectangle to this view's background.
     *
     * @param rect
     *            a rectangle used to unmask the background
     */
    public void addUnmaskRect(Rect rect) {
        mRects.add(rect);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (Rect r : mRects) {
            canvas.drawRect(r, mUnmaskPaint);
        }
    }

}
```

Your `Fragment` (or whatever is keeping track of the unmask areas) passes `Rect`s to `MaskView` via `addUnmaskRect(Rect)`. Whenever the view is redrawn (remember to call `invalidate()` each time you are done passing `Rect`s) it is first filled with black, and then has any rectangles unmask the black background.  The coordinates for your rectangles must be set to the coordinate space of the view, but if the underlying image occupies the exact same area it should be relatively simple (you can also look at the `View.getLocationInWindow(int[])` method to help you with this as well).

Comment: I have tried using your unmask paint example like this: `canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 30, mUnmaskPaint);` and the app closes (but does not crash).  In LogCat I can see `07-07 20:04:29.806: A/libc(26164): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 26164 (<app>)
`.  Any idea?  I feel like I'm close.

Comment: Glad it works!  I would be wary about creating new objects in onDraw() however...it is supposed to be as lightweight as possible.  If you run Android Lint on your project, it may pop a warning saying the same thing.  I think the best thing to do would be to create and set up the paint elsewhere and just keep it in memory as an instance variable for the life of the view.